# Macro works but too slow

Tags: excel, vba

I found this macro that does the job but it takes very long to execute. I would like it to go over rows 4 to 350 instead of all rows. Plus I would like it not to ask which sheet but execute on sheet name Data. The macro is used to delete empty rows.

```
Sub DeleteBlankRows()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngIdx As Long, _
        lngColCounter As Long
    Dim blnAllBlank As Boolean
    Dim UserInputSheet As String
    
    UserInputSheet = Application.InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet which you wish to remove empty rows from")
    
    Set wks = Worksheets(UserInputSheet)
    
    With wks
        'Now that our sheet is defined, we'll find the last row and last column
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    
        'Since we need to delete rows, we start from the bottom and move up
        For lngIdx = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1
    
            'Start by setting a flag to immediately stop checking
            'if a cell is NOT blank and initializing the column counter
            blnAllBlank = True
            lngColCounter = 2
    
            'Check cells from left to right while the flag is True
            'and the we are within the farthest-right column
            While blnAllBlank And lngColCounter <= lngLastCol
    
                'If the cell is NOT blank, trip the flag and exit the loop
                If .Cells(lngIdx, lngColCounter) <> "" Then
                    blnAllBlank = False
                Else
                    lngColCounter = lngColCounter + 1
                End If
    
            Wend
    
            'Delete the row if the blnBlank variable is True
            If blnAllBlank Then
                .Rows(lngIdx).Delete
            End If
    
        Next lngIdx
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Blank rows have been deleted."

End Sub
```

Comment: In this loop `For lngIdx = lngLastRow To 1 Step -1` define `lngLastRow` as 350 and `1` as `4` so it runs from `350` to `4` and instead of `Set wks = Worksheets(UserInputSheet)` write your sheet name `Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")` you wish to execute it on.

Comment: If you just want to delete blank rows, why not just sort the sheet? That will move the blank rows to the bottom and thus "remove" them. Or  `Set wks = ActiveSheet`

Comment: @Andreas because sorting will sort the data and if that is not what he wants it will mess everything up. Sorting data is not removing blanks that's totally different.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the sheet or data, sorting seems like the simpler way to get the job done. I'd prefer if we leave it to OP to set the boundaries of what is OK/Not OK to do with the data.

Comment: I tryed PEH solution but does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to delete rows if all cells in that row are blank.

Your actual code checks every single cell from every row and column in your datarange.

You can improve speed just checking if the full row is blank or not. As example:

[image]

Yellow cells are blank cells
Red cells are **complete** blank rows (all cells in that row are blanks).

This code will delete the red rows, that means it will delete **entire row** but only if all cells are blank.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim MyRow As Range, DeleteRange As Range
Dim MiF As WorksheetFunction

Set MiF = WorksheetFunction

Set rng = Range("C7:M34") 'define range here

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    If MiF.CountA(rng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        If DeleteRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DeleteRange = rng.Rows(i) 'first time, we can't use Union
        Else
            'we unite all complete blank rows into one final "big" range
            Set DeleteRange = Union(DeleteRange, rng.Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

'we delete if something is found
If Not DeleteRange Is Nothing Then DeleteRange.EntireRow.Delete

'clear variables
Set DeleteRange = Nothing
Set rng = Nothing
Set MiF = Nothing
```

After executing code, output is like this.

[image]

Comment: It does the job partially blank rows are still present!

Comment: What do you mean *partially*?

Comment: It does the first 3 tables but not the next 2.

Comment: Hi, I found the reason and it works ! Thanks !